# How to find the maximum value along the topmost row and leftmost column of a subarray in a 2d array?

Tags: java

If I have a 2D array such as below, I need to get the maximum value for the top most row and left most column (one value) and store the coordinates (I, J) of that value. I then need to consider the subarray to the bottom right of that value and again, find the maximum value from the topmost row or left most column. This will continue throughout the entire 2D array so that I will end up with an Nx2 array of coordinates of all values obtained.
For example, in the matrix shown, the values should be 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0, with coordinates (0, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4) respectively.

```
4 2 2 1 0 
2 3 2 1 0
2 2 1 1 1  
1 1 2 1 0 
1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0
```

I have tried the following but the top left corner of each subarray always starts at the diagonal (i.e. (0, 0), (1, 1)....) rather than the value immediately below and to the right of the previous maximum value. For example if the previous maximum value had coordinates (3, 2) then the top left corner of the next subarray should be (4, 3).

```
// Top left corner of subarray set each time.

for(int p = 0; p < myMatrix.length; p++){  
    int maximum = myMatrix[p][p];
       coordinates[p][0] = p;
       coordinates[p][1] = p;

// Iterates through leftmost column of subarray.
    for(int i = p; i < table_data.length; i++){  
        if(maximum <= myMatrix[i][p]){            
           maximum = myMatrix[i][p];
           coordinates[p][0] = i;
           coordinates[p][1] = p;
       }
    }

//Iterates through topmost row of subarray. 

    for(int j = p; j < myMatrix[0].length; j++){ 
        if(maximum <= table_data[p][j]){           
        maximum = myMatrix[p][j];                   
        coordinates[p][0] = p;                     
        coordinates[p][1] = j;
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't get the relation between `myMatrix` and `table_data`. I guess you don't need both.

Also you iterate in them as being independent while I guess they should be the same matrix.

Also the sample data you present does not have the same number of rows and columns. I don't know if that's intentional but if so you have not specified where the search stops; in the number of rows or columns.

Anyway taking this into account here is a working solution.

```
    int[][] myMatrix = {{4, 2, 2, 1, 0} ,
                        {2, 3, 2, 1, 0},
                        {2, 2, 1, 1, 1},  
                        {1, 1, 2, 1, 0}, 
                        {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
                        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}  };
    int coordinates[][] = new int[myMatrix.length][2];
    int maximum[] = new int[myMatrix.length];
    int m = Math.min(myMatrix.length, myMatrix[0].length);
    for(int p = 0; p < m; p++){  
        maximum[p] = myMatrix[p][p];
        coordinates[p][0] = p;
        coordinates[p][1] = p;
        for(int j = p; j < myMatrix[p].length; j++){ 
            if(maximum[p] <= myMatrix[p][j]){           
                maximum[p] = myMatrix[p][j];                   
                coordinates[p][0] = p;                     
                coordinates[p][1] = j;
            }
        }
        for(int i = p; i < myMatrix[p].length; i++){  
            if(maximum[p] <= myMatrix[i][p]){            
               maximum[p] = myMatrix[i][p];
               coordinates[p][0] = i;
               coordinates[p][1] = p;
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I only needed myMatrix, the table_data variable was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you always start from the point p,p at the p-th iteration. 
Instead, you could use two variables

```
int top = coordinates[p][0] + 1;
int left = coordinates[p][1] + 1;
```

and write the loops using them, something like

```
for(int i = left; i < table_data.length; i++){  
    if(maximum <= myMatrix[i][top]){
```

(I might have inverted x and y, but this is the idea).

Then you also need to modify your enclosing loop, which can not always have p iteration. instead, a "while" loop checking that top and left are still in the bounds of the matrix would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    int[][] aa = { { 4, 2, 2, 1, 0 }, { 2, 3, 2, 1, 0 }, { 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 2, 1, 0 }, { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 } };
    int[][] temp = aa;
    printArray(aa);
    System.out.println("---------------------");

    while ((temp = getArray(temp)) != null) {
        printArray(temp);

        System.out.println("---------------------");
    }

}

static int[][] getArray(int[][] aa) {
    int row = aa.length;
    int col = aa[0].length;
    if (row == 2 || col == 2) { // we can also try if (row == 1 || col == 1) to get the last array
        return null;
    }
    int[][] temp = new int[row - 1][col - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < col; j++) {
            temp[i - 1][j - 1] = aa[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

static void printArray(int aa[][]) {
    int row = aa.length;
    int col = aa[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            System.out.print(aa[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```